# save disabled on sitecore page editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

I'm been working with Sitecore for a while, but this is my first time on the page editor.
So, I go to my sublayout and I place a sitecore tag instead a .net tag

```
<sc:Text ID="txtContent" Field="Content" runat="server"/>
```

Content is the normal content field on the sitecore page.
When I go to the page editor, I'm able to see the correct content and do some editing but the save button is disabled and my changes are not saved at all
I'm I missing something very basic here?

this is a screen cast on what I'm doing
http://screencast.com/t/0itqgjGVQx8

Update: After including jquery.noconflict constructs, the execution moves to the handler function in the ribbon correctly. BUT it seems that the button itself is disabled. Is it possible to enable/disable the button? is it disable on specific situations? if so how can I enable it.

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: I'm running version 6.4

Comment: From the top of my head I would say that you are logged into the Page Editor with limited privileges but on the other hand it seems like you are able to save when in Content Editor.
Are you logged in as Admin or another account?

Comment: Any JavaScript errors being thrown? Check the console window in Firebug. Are you using $ for all your jQuery code? That's a known issue in 6.4 (which uses a different library) if you are not using closures and scopes correctly.

Comment: Actually I'm getting an error this.desing is undefined.... I was using $ and I changed it to jQuery, next thing I'm going to use jquery non conflict. What annoying is this prototype, does anyone know if sitecore finally got rid of it?

Comment: So I've wrapped my jquery
this is what I get:

    TypeError: this.design is undefined in firebug console. There is also a reference to the source line in this function:


this.hoverActive = function() {
return !this.design.sorting;
};
on ChromeManager.Js

Comment: If I click save, now I can hit my breakpoint in the event handler, goes to this function
function scSave(postaction) {
var saveButton = $('scRibbonButton_Save');
//Workaround for FF not appriciating disabled attribute
if (saveButton && saveButton.disabled) {
return;
}
on webeditribbon.js
saveButton  is undefined so the control exit the function right away.

Comment: Correction saveButon.disabled is true (not undefined)

Comment: Please consider moving these details to the question section. This will make the question easier to work with, and of greater future reference value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolve this some time ago... in the sublayout definition on sitecore there was a redundant/wrong compatible rendering definition. Once I removed that, the save button appeared and the sublayout started to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

There might be invalid html appearing. Check you hints for buttons, etc. There might be non-escaped texts on the page.